# Ubuntu in VirtualBox wants to install on every boot

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox

I am running VirtualBox on Windows. I have a virtual machine that I installed Ubuntu on. When I shut it down (from Ubuntu shut down button) and then later launch it again, it asks me to install it again. Do I have to install Ubuntu every time I launch it in VirtualBox?

Comment: Please be more specific in your question. It's always a good idea to post the exact message you see, for instance, along with any version numbers. In this case, details that would be helpful include: Windows version, VirtualBox version, and Ubuntu version. Also, edit your post to give the exact settings you used in VirtualBox.

Comment: Could it be an issue with the iso attached to the cdrom drive? When you restart its reading from the cd and trying to re install again.

Comment: Like @Matt said it sounds to me that the iso is still mounted and virtual box is trying to reinstall. Unmount the iso.

Comment: Matt is right, i couldnt find anywhere to plug it off so i thought its not possible, until now i looked at the device list on the virtual window, but that required me to restart it again because it already read it. is it anyhow possible to plug it off without starting the ubuntu?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Could it be an issue with the iso attached to the cdrom drive? When you restart its reading from the cd and trying to re install again.

Comment: Right hand click on the CD icon at the bottom when starting virtual machine, then change it to Host Drive D: then reboot. This should not use your iso to boot.

Comment: I was stuck in OpenBSD install loop and this worked as well. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

after the installation is complete, in the virtualBox window, go to settings, there in the storage tab, you can see controller:SATA
check if it has .iso selected, if so, then change it to the folder you selected the virtual operating to be installed.